# Question about finite dimensional representations of a semi-simple Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I've encountered the following paragraph while reading  page 3 of this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01232026?noAccess=true

> Let $G$ be a semi-simple Lie group with a maximal compact subgroup $K$. Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{s}$ be the corresponding Cartan decomposition. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$  over $\mathbb{R}$.
> There exists a $K$-invariant inner product $(,)$ on $V$ such that any $X \in \mathfrak{s}$ acts as a symmetric operator.

I know that since $K$ is a compact subgroup, there exists a $K$-invariant inner product $(,)$ on $V$, but I don't know why there is such an inner product for which every $X \in \mathfrak{s}$ acts as a symmetric operator ? Any help please.

Comment: I have posted this question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424416/question-about-finite-dimensional-representations-of-a-semi-simple-lie-group?noredirect=1#comment1090923_424416